# memory map of a shared library in linux

Tags: linux, memory-management, process

When I look at a process's memory map using

cat /proc/pid/maps

There are entries like this:

```
40321000-40336000 r-xp 00000000 b3:15 875        /system/lib/libm.so
40336000-40337000 r--p 00014000 b3:15 875        /system/lib/libm.so
40337000-40338000 rw-p 00015000 b3:15 875        /system/lib/libm.so
40338000-40345000 r-xp 00000000 b3:15 789        /system/lib/libcutils.so
40345000-40346000 r--p 0000c000 b3:15 789        /system/lib/libcutils.so
40346000-40347000 rw-p 0000d000 b3:15 789        /system/lib/libcutils.so
40347000-40355000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
40355000-403bc000 r-xp 00000000 b3:15 877        /system/lib/libmedia.so
403bc000-403bd000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
403bd000-403d0000 r--p 00067000 b3:15 877        /system/lib/libmedia.so
403d0000-403d1000 rw-p 0007a000 b3:15 877        /system/lib/libmedia.so
403d1000-403d5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
403d5000-403d8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
```

I understand the .so represents the shared libraries the process maps. It seems each .so has 3 entries and their permissions are
    r-xp
    r--p
    rw-p

So how do I interpret this? Can I assume the r-xp is the code section of the library, since it has the x (execute) permission? How about the r--p and rw-p, are they the data sections?

What about the empty entries? For example, the last 6 entries about libmedia have three empty entires (00:00 0). What are these?

```
403bc000-403bd000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
403bd000-403d0000 r--p 00067000 b3:15 877        /system/lib/libmedia.so
403d0000-403d1000 rw-p 0007a000 b3:15 877        /system/lib/libmedia.so
403d1000-403d5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
403d5000-403d8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
```

Comment: It seems like (at least some of) the sections with no associated file might be anonymous maps for memory allocated at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I assume the r-xp is the code section of the library, since it has
>   the x (execute) permission?

Yes, but this is known as text segment(which stores the instruction). You should also note that it does not have write permission as it should not have.

> How about the r--p and rw-p, are they the data sections?

Yes,These segments store the static/global variable. However constant global variable would be stored into r--p segment as it should not be modifiable by any program.

> What about the empty entries? For example, the last 6 entries about
>   libmedia have three empty entires (00:00 0). What are these?
>   These might be the guard segment(kernel inserts these segments to protect the overflow scenario). The **"p"** indicates that its private.

**EDIT**
For complete information, you may want to refer the following link:

http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc